# Sphinx - No tokenizer found for language fr, cs etc

Tags: python, python-sphinx, spell-checking

I'm using Sphinx for documentation purpose. I want to use a spell-check handling French.

So far, I have done the following:

- installing sphinx spellcheck extension

> ```
> sudo pip install sphinxcontrib-spelling
> ```

- installing French language

> ```
>  sudo apt-get install myspell-fr-fr
> ```

- add extension in conf.py

> ```
>  extensions = ["sphinxcontrib.spelling"]
>  spelling_lang='fr'
> ```

- add spelling builder

> builder = ["html", "pdf", "spelling" ],

Here is the traceback I get while running Sphinx :

```
Exception occurred:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sphinx/cmdline.py", line 188, in main
warningiserror, tags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sphinx/application.py", line 134, in __init__
self._init_builder(buildername)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sphinx/application.py", line 194, in _init_builder
self.builder = builderclass(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sphinx/builders/__init__.py", line 57, in __init__
self.init()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sphinxcontrib/spelling.py", line 253, in init
filters=filters,
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sphinxcontrib/spelling.py", line 181, in __init__
self.tokenizer = get_tokenizer(lang, filters)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/enchant/tokenize/__init__.py", line 186, in get_tokenizer
raise TokenizerNotFoundError(msg)
TokenizerNotFoundError: No tokenizer found for language 'fr'
```

Comment: Have you installed enchant and pyenchant?

Comment: I've installed the following packages: python3-enchant, python-sphinxcontrib.spelling, enchant, libenchant-dev, python-enchant, still have the pb (I'm runing on Ubuntu 12.04)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add tokenizer for given language into `PyEnchant`.

## Quick and dirty solution

Clone the pyenchant repo and cd into it:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:rfk/pyenchant.git
$ cd pyenchant
```

Go to directory, where are tokenizers defined:

```
$ cd enchant/tokenize
```

Copy the existing `en.py` tokenizer to language code you want to use (I was missing `cs`, you can try `fr`):

```
$ cp en.py cs.py
$ cp en.py fr.py
```

Install the package from this modified code:

```
$ cd ../..  # first return to the dir with `setup.py`
$ pip install -e .
```

And now it shall work (it works for me).

Better solution would be to review the copied tokenizer and modify where it does not fit your language. And contribute to `pyenchant`.

Comment: I didn't follow every step, just C&P the "en.py" from my enchant installation into a "fr.py" and it works, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I hit the same error and it looks like this has nothing to do with missing dictionaries.

PyEnchant simply doesn't ship with a French tokenizer yet but only an English one. As noted in the [Extending enchant.tokenize](https://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/tutorial.html#extending-enchant-tokenize) documentation:

> The author would be very grateful for tokenization routines for languages other than English which can be incorporated back into the main PyEnchant distribution.